# Using Quartz CronScheduleBuilder No Job Executed

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, jobs

This trigger should be fired every day at 9:00 PM however the job is never run. If I use .WithSimpleSchedule() the job will run but I need to use a CronSchedule, am I setting it up wrong?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().WithIdentity("Test").Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Test")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(9, 00))
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

My job which does not fire.

```
public class EmailJob : IJob
{
    public EmailJob()
    {

    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method Called");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why CronScheduleBuilder doesn't work, but using .WithCronSchedule does. Here is a working trigger that will fire at 6:30 AM. I used http://www.cronmaker.com/ to create the cron string.

```
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Test")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 30 6 1/1 * ? *")
            .Build();
```

Comment: Did you manage to find why it is not working with ```WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(9, 00))
```